Changed the disc brake rotor, now wheel doesn't spin?
I have replaced the tire and the disc brake rotor on my rear wheel and since then for some reasons my rear wheel does not spin.
When I take off the disc brake rotor it freely spins:
https://vimeo.com/930142655
But when I put back the rotor and start to fasten the thru axle it stops spinning:
https://vimeo.com/930142637
I checked if it rubs the brake pads but seems like there is sufficient gap there:

so I have really no idea what I did wrong..
I tried to put back the old rotor, and now having the same issue 
I even tried that I loosen the bolts on the brake housing an spin the wheel but still the same issue, so I think it is not that the housing is touching the rotor..
For now I took off the cassette and the rotor from this wheel and put them on my old wheel and there there is no issue.. Did I damage something within the wheel or what?
I use 160mm disc brake rotor (like the previous), and fastened it with 40Nm as it suggests.
Any help is appreciated,
Matt
Update:
After further investigation I found the culprit:

I am not sure what the name of this but this circular part got loose and when I fastened the centerlock it was touching that, thus blocking the axle from spinning.
Many thanks for the tips, I’ve learned a lot again.

That's a well documented question - thank you.   Are there any washers or spacers which may have been missed,rotated, or had their stacking order changed ?

@Criggie nothing. Previous was a dura ace rotor, this one is ultegra, other than that no changes.

Thanks for adding images to your question, unfortunately the videos seem to be "not rated", therefore requireing log-in. Is there anything you can change in your Vimeo settings to "rate" the video and make it public?

@SaaruLindestøkke I viewed both videos okay without being logged in  ?

Hmm, maybe a geo-restriction or some other issue on my end then... I can't see the videos: https://i.imgur.com/TDy60ax.png

Since the problem only exists with the disk in lace, but seems not related to the caliper, i'd suggest looking if the disk at the hub gets in contact with the frame.

@SaaruLindestøkke I’ve set the ratings for all audiences, can you please have a look again?

@Mat thanks, that works! Glad that you found the issue. If you want you can actually post it as an answer (instead of as an edit to your question) and accept it.

Something is clearly binding, and it happens when you tighten the through axle.
That will subtly clamp the dropouts to the side of the wheel.  It should NOT be preloading any bearings, which will be cartridge style.
I'd do more investigation.  Use a piece of printer paper to try and spot what is slack when the TA is loose, and bites when teh TA is tightened.   It may be axle, or it may be the caliper, with a small chance it could be something elsewhere on the wheel like a mudguard.
I find working with at-least two bright lights helps a lot - as does a clean bike and work bench.    Good luck !
